# A problem with automatic text wrapping in longtable

Tags: tables, longtable, wrap, python

I wrote a script that generates LaTeX tables from a pandas.DataFrame, hence they may have different numbers of columns. I want to wrap text therein automatically.

Following [this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1918465/8849135), I went for

`\begin{longtable}{l >{\raggedright}p{0.75\textwidth} }`

however this returns and error:

`Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr`

Typically, tables look like that:

```
\begin{longtable}{l >{\raggedright}p{0.75\textwidth}}
\toprule
bla bla & \multicolumn{3}{l}{bla bla} \\
\midrule
\endhead
\midrule
\multicolumn{5}{r}{{Continued on next page}} \\
\midrule
\endfoot

\bottomrule
\endlastfoot
 bla bla &   &  bla bla &   &   \\
\end{longtable}
```

Comment: You have declared 2 columns but use 3 and 5 with your multicolumn.

Comment: you also need `>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}`  so that `\\ ` retains its meaning of end of table row.

Answer (score -2):

expanding on the comment by @UlrikeFischer

```
\begin{longtable}{l >{\raggedright}p{0.75\textwidth}} % <------- total 2 columns
\toprule
bla bla & \multicolumn{1}{l}{bla bla} \\% <------------total 2 columns
\midrule
\endhead
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{r}{{Continued on next page}} \\% <------------ total 2 columns
\midrule
\endfoot

\bottomrule
\endlastfoot
 bla bla &   bla bla    \\ % <------------ total 2 columns
\end{longtable}
```

Comment: I assume you didn't try this (`\\ ` will not work in this context)